# How to check the WebSeal Server Junction connectivity?

Tags: webseal

I have to check the connectivity to the portal which is behind the WebSeal Server. I need the response code of the actual server and WebSeal server code too. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning on debugging.  Ideally, you are the only traffic on the server.  Make sure to turn it on before you do anything that may be related to the problem (i.e. logging in) then wait at least 1 min after the problem occurs to let the logs catch up.

```
server task default-webseald-xxxx trace set pdweb.snoop 9 file path=c:/pdweb.snoop.txt,rollover_size=100000000

server task default-webseald-xxxx trace set pdweb.debug 9 file path=c:/pdweb.debug.txt,rollover_size=100000000
```

Make sure to turn it off afterwards as it will destroy your hard drives.

```
 server task default-webseald-xxxx trace set pdweb.snoop 0
 server task default-webseald-xxxx trace set pdweb.debug 0
```

Answer (score 0):

WebSEAL constantly checks the backend servers within the junction.  If you use pdadmin to do `server task SERVER show /junction` you can see if the backend server is online or offline.

I am assuming you mean HTTP response code.  You can get that from WebSEAL by doing a simple HTTP/S get like you would any regular HTTP server.  However, for the backend server, you will need to go around WebSEAL and connect to the backend directly to perform your checks.

If you are trying to setup monitoring, you can do one of two things.  Either watch the msg__webseal-default.log for the following lines:

```
DPWWA2025W IBM Security Access Manager WebSEAL has lost contact with junction server:
```

Or you can use the server task command to show the junction and look for the `Server State:` being `running` or `not running`.